# Add and remove src attribute and contents muiltiple times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, attributes

I've built a modal to play a YouTube clips when clicked from a list and stop when the window is closed. I can get it to work fine (open/play and then close/stop). However, when I trigger it again it wont add the src attribute back to the iframe element again:

HTML:

```
<a class="cinema__play" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1234567890?vq=HD1080&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" href="#">Play</a>

<div class="cinema">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <a class="cinema__close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <iframe class="cinema__video" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.cinema__play').click(function() {
    $code = $(this).data('video');
    $(".cinema__video").attr("src", $code);
    return false;
});

$('.cinema__close').click(function() {
    $(".cinema__video").removeAttr("src");
    return false;
});
```

For the record, I am working on a better YouTube API version to do this (stop video on modal close), but I do need this version to work, for now.

Comment: Can you create a simple demo?

Comment: popping it in here doesn't seem to reproduce the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/af55hs7j/6/

Comment: can you check over the JSFiddle and see if a) there is a problem I've missed; or b) there is not actually the problem you report, or the problem you report is elsewhere, in code not shared (yet)?

Comment: This is weird - I've got it working properly (my question) in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0aq4ot2c/2

Comment: Here is the full working modal: http://jsfiddle.net/0aq4ot2c/4/